# take a list of filters and return all possible combinations

Tags: python, pandas, styles

I'm using pandas. I have a list of filters to be used as part of dataframe.loc[filter, :], eg.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size=[10,8]))

filter1 = df[1] == True
filter2 = df[5] == False
filter3 = (df[2] == True) & (df[7] == False)

filters = [filter1, filter2, filter3]
```

How do I generate a list/dictionary of all possible combinations of filters?
eg.

```
{combination_1 : (filter_1),
combination_2 : (filter_1 & filter_2),
combination_3 : (filter_1 & filter_3),
combination_4 : (filter_1 & filter_2, & filter_3),
etc.}
```

so that I can loop over the list and apply a different function to the dataframe for each combination. I want to do this so I can highlight each row a different colour depending on which combination of the filters was true.

I have written a function to generate a hex string:

```
def hex_string(filter_1, filter_2, filter_3):
    bool_list = [filter_1, filter_2, filter_3]
    hex_list = ["FF" if value else "00" for value in bool_list]
    string = f"#{''.join(hexlist)}"
    return string
```

The idea would be that I would style my dataframe with a function that looks something like this

```
def highlight_rows(dataframe):
    df = dataframe.copy()
    iterable = combination_generator_function(filter_list)

    for combination in iterable:
        df.loc[combination,:] = "background-color:{hex_string(combination)}"
    return df

df.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis=None)
```

I feel like this should be a lot easier than I'm making it out to be. Is it possible to do this without typing out each individual combination and the hex string that would go with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce

filter_combos = [
    reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, combo)
    for i in range(1, len(filters) + 1)
    for combo in combinations(filters, i)
]
```

To illustrate: `combinations(filters, 2)` gives you the tuples

```
(filter1, filter2), (filter1, filter3), (filter2, filter3)
```

and the `reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, combo)` "reduces" tuples like `(filter1, filter2)` via the lambda-function to `filter1 & filter2`. ([`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce) works cumulatively from left to right, i.e. it works not only for tuples with 2 elements. And for tuples with only one element it returns just the element.)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I ran into a slight problem in that '&' did not combine the two filters in the way I wanted. i.e. I wanted:
```
filter1 = pandas.Series([True, False, True])

filter2 = pandas.Series([True, True, False])

reduce(lambda x, y: x&y, (filter1, filter2)) = pandas.Series([True, False, False])
```
I solved this by converting the series to numpy arrays. but your answer covered everything I asked.

P.S. I'm very new to posting on stack overflow. In terms of ettiquette, should I be doing anything other than upvoting your answer?

Comment: @Linden Glad I could help. Re 'etiquette': All good.

Answer (score 0):

I think itertools is a good solution here.

```
import itertools  
filters = [filter_1, filter_2, filter_3]  

combinationList = []

for i in range(len(filters)):  
    combinationList += list(itertools.permutations(filters,i+1))

print(combinationList) #Probably cant print the filters, but combinationList is the list off all possible combinations from 1-3 filters per combination
```